# What's the difference between XHTML and DHTML?

Tags: xhtml, dhtml

Reading about both separatedly, looks like the same, html+xml+javascript.

What's the difference between then? Is there any?

Comment: read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_HTML & http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[XHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML) is a [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/) standard, a form of HTML that also strictly conforms to XML.

[DHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_HTML) is a largely deprecated term (it is short for 'Dynamic HTML') which was introduced when the first early static web sites started introducing client side scripting to make the page more 'dynamic'. Nobody really talks in terms of DHTML any more (the term got superseded by 'ajax', and 'web 2.0', and 'web app')

Answer (score 3):

No, neither one is HTML + XML + Javascript.

**XHTML is HTML (but also XML)**
It's just a dialect of HTML that conforms to the syntax rules of XML. Javascript is not part of the XHTML specification (or any HTML specification).

**DHTML is HTML + Javascript**
It stands for *Dynamic HTML*, and Javascript adds the dynamic part. The HTML part can also be the dialect XHTML.

Answer (score 1):

1. XHTML is a dialect that is based on the XML language while DHTML is not a dialect or a language but a collection of other technologies
2. Both were created to provide additional features and interactivity to HTML
3. DHTML still uses HTML at its core and is plagued with HTML related problems
4. XHTML is more streamlined and easier to code with because of its conformance to XML
5. DHTML is already outdated and has been replaced by other technologies

take a look to this post: 
http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-dhtml-and-xhtml/

Answer (score -1):

DHTML is dynamic HTML, means the contents of html becomes dynamic and changes time to time and did not require developer again after one time creation of language.
XHTML extensive HTML means this is also uses XML , simple is that in XML you can build your own tags and used in your project or file.